# Can ThreadAbortException be raised in the middle of a Finally Block?

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, thread-safety

Asuming the following code is running in a seperate Thread:

```
try{
  var stuffToDispose = new SomeClassThatNeedsDisposing();
  //doing thing with stuffToDispose
}
finally{
   if(stuffToDispose != null)
     stuffToDispose.Dispose();
}
```

and this thread is aborted using the mechanic that raises the `ThreadAbortException`. Could the `ThreadAbortException` happen between the null-check and the Dispose()? Aka, in the middle of the finally block?

```
finally{
   if(stuffToDispose != null)
     //This is where the Exception would strike
     stuffToDispose.Dispose();
}
```

I am pretty sure the answer is no, but someone else seems convinced it is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **.NET Framework** `ThreadAbortException` is handled in a special way both in `catch` and `finally` blocks:

- If a `ThreadAbortException` is caught, it is automatically re-raised at the end of the `catch` block (unless it is suppressed by `Thread.ResetAbort`)
- In a `finally` block the `ThreadAbortException` will not be 'activated' until the end of the whole block. This is an intended behavior. And that's why you can find sometimes [obscure codes](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,2114) with and empty `try {}` block where everything is in the `finally` section. It guarantees that this section will not be aborted.

On the other hand, **.NET Core** does not support `Thread.Abort` (throws a `PlatformNotSupportedException`). The `ThreadAbortException` itself has not been removed (for compatibility reasons) so you can still throw it explicitly but I don't think it is still handled as described above (I did not test it).

Comment: Wow, it means finally can be used to prevent abortion of some section? This is new to me and very helpfull! Though in <.NET 4 it will still be aborted....

Comment: Yes, at least until the end of the finally block. Which of course can be exploited badly as you can see from the examples.

Comment: Aside from the CORE issue, this is exactly how I thought it would work once I read about the "can not be swallowed" protection/re-raising.

Answer (score 2):

**Finally will not be interrupted if**

Running this code under **.NET 4.0.0-4.7.2** will lock infinitelly on `Thread.Abort()` printing `foo` and hanging in finally:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var i = false;
        var t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            try { Console.Write("foo"); } finally { while (true) { i=true; } }
        });
        t.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        t.Abort();
        t.Join();
        Console.WriteLine("bar = {0}", i);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Still, there is no guarantee that this will not execute sometimes in further versions.

**Finally will be executed but interrupted if**

Running same section under **.NET 2.0-3.5** will print `foobar = True`, which implies it is interrupted.

But if you modify it like so:

```
        var t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            try { Console.Write("foo"); } finally { while (true) { Console.Write(".");} }
        });
```

It will run infinitelly like in first sample. This is ... strange.

**Summary**

Better to ask it dirrectly at Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

According to my tests, calling `Thread.Abort` does not interrupt a currently running finally block inside the thread.

Test code:

```
var thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    try
    {
    }
    catch (ThreadAbortException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ThreadAbortException");
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread Finally Started");
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        Console.WriteLine("Thread Finally Finished");
    }
})
{ IsBackground = true };
thread.Start();
Thread.Sleep(100);
Console.WriteLine("Aborting...");
thread.Abort();
thread.Join();
```

Output (.NET Framework 4.8):

> Thread Finally Started
>   Aborting...
>   Thread Finally Finished

Keep in mind that [`Thread.Abort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.abort) is not supported on .NET Core.

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Thread abort is not supported on this platform.

Comment: The strange things happens if you write something like *while(true){ i++;}* in finally and run under < .NET 4.0, it will be interrupted. Used your example.

Comment: @eocron writing code for .NET Framework < 4.0 is sad anyway. No TPL, no async/await. How `Thread.Abort` behaves would be the least of my problems. :-)

Comment: Yeah, but important to mention, to obsolete old answers =) Cause I believed in it's interruption up to 4.8 =)